# can anyone use my application.app file to install the app in his device

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is this possible that anyother person run the app on the his device by taking my application.app file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not without a valid mobile profile on the device. What you're looking for is called "Ad Hoc" distribution. You need to create/update a distribution certifcate with the other persons device id added, and use that to sign your app & create the mobile profiles. Details are on the Apple developer site, and on a few blogs.